# Kibana query results mismatch between _count & _search api

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Am executing below kibana query, when i execute `_count` api am getting `count:45`. But if i execute same query with `_search` api on the same index, am getting only `10` documents in response instead of `45` documents

Please find the below kibana query

```
GET documents_test2/_count
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "*",
            "query" : "40011"
        }
    }
}
```

For the above Kibana query am getting below response with the `count:45`

```
{
  "count": 45,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

But if i execute the below query with `_search` api instead of `_count` am getting only `10` doucuments in response

```
GET documents_test2/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "*",
            "query" : "40011"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, when your use "**_search**" , it uses "**size**" param to return the no. of relevant documents. and since you are not passing that param here, it **default value is passed , which is 10**. hence only 10 documents are return.

Pass "Size" param value to return as many documents you want.

```
GET documents_test2/_search
{
   "size" : 45,
   "query": {
     "query_string" : {
        "default_field" : "*",
        "query" : "40011"
    }
}
```

You can also check "**From**" param to get the paginated results (sliding window) from elastic search. 
e.g. if you want to get 3rd page documents with page size as 10, you can pass "Size" : 10 , "From" : 20 (i.e. pagesize X (pageno. - 1) = 10 *  (3-1) = 10 X 2 = 20

Check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html for more details.